# How can I iterate through an array within an array of a struct using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm given a struct:

```
struct Agency {
    char name[255];
    int zip[5];
    RentalCar inventory[5];     // array of RentalCar objects
};
```

I need to retrieve data from a file to fill an array of 3 Agency objects.
To set the values for the first item in the inventory array is easy,

```
Agency ag[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
ag->inventory->setWhatever();
ag++;     // easy to iterate through this array
}
```

But It's not that easy to iterate through the inventory array within the agency array.

```
inventory++;        // doesn't know what object this is associated with
ag->inventory++;    // also doesn't work
```

Comment: Do you know how to read *one* `RentalCar` from the file?

Comment: Can you not do ag[0].inventory[1] for example to access the second RentalCar from the first Agency? Would it be ok or do you need to do this through pointers?

Comment: Anyway, there you go

Comment: @Beta yes, and I can write over the first one in the array as many times as I want, I just can't get to the second or anything passed that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Agency ag[3];
Agency *ag_ptr= &ag[0]; // or: Agency *ag_ptr = ag; //as this decays to pointer
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Rentalcar *rental_ptr = ag_ptr->inventory; //rental_ptr now points at the first RentalCar
    rental_ptr->setWhatever(); //set first rental car
    rental_ptr++;
    rental_ptr->setWhatever(); //set second rental car
    ag_ptr++;
}
```

Arrays can be accessed through index, for example `ag[0] ag[1] ag[2]` but this is illegal: `ag++`. The array name `ag` decays to pointer to first element when used alone, but it is not a pointer.

Pointers, on the other hand can scroll memory address with + and - operations. Be wary, because they could easily point to memory not reserved for your program.

Comment: I can't use the array index operator `[ ]`, only for declaring array. I know it's stupid but that's what's required. But if I were able to use `ptr->inventory[1]->setWhatever();` wouldn't it be `ptr->inventory[1].setWhatever();` since `inventory[1]` is a variable not a pointer?

Comment: @griffin175 `Agency *ptr = &ag[0];` and `Agency *ptr = ag;` result in the same thing. That should eliminate all of the `[]`s used to index.

Comment: @user4581301 Sure thing.